# Dynamically applying filter to list of products in ecommerce application

Tags: java, sql, algorithm, e-commerce

I need some of your inputs in deciding a right approach in following case.

I am currently working on a ecommerce application ( An online shopping website).
Here, on homepage of application, I have to display a list of products available in shop.

The end user has a facility of applying a filter to products list so that only the products satisfying the applied filter will be displayed.( Filter like display products with selected company,price range and so on ).

So, my question is regarding the logic for applying the filter.
I have following ideas in mind to implement this requirement.

1. As user selects different criterias on page, generate SQL query dynamically( By appending a string with required where clauses) and fire the generated SQL on each request.
2. Set up all possible combinations of SQLs in database already ( say in a stored procedure ). As user changes the criteria, select the appropriate SQL in stored procedure to run.

Can anyone please guide me, if there is any better way to handle this requirement ?
Any input is highly appreaciated.
Please let me know if more information is required in this context.

Thanks.

Comment: I would opt for 2nd Option.. First of all it will increase the speed of application as you haven't to generated SQL on each request. and Second it is not susceptible to SQL injection...

Comment: your ecommerce application use jpa? storeprocedures? or it's totally a new project?

Comment: @nachokk : It's a new project. I have no idea about JPA. Would it be useful ? Does it offers the API to filter the resultset based on some business logic ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the first one, but you've got to be wary of SQL injection attacks.

I don't like your second option because stored procedures are usually written in a language that I consider worse than java.  That's pure opinion, but that's my opinion.  They also aren't database agnostic.

Alternatively, you can use JPA for this. For example, there are [Hibernate Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Something that works well for sites like yours is to not change the query to retrieve different items to offer for sale but, instead, to offer the all the same items but to change the order they appear on the site.

So, if the user wants items priced $100-$500, you still show the items under $100 and over $500 but the ones in that range appear first, then the ones outside the range in some sort of random order. Or, if there are multiple criteria, you may show items meeting all but one of the criteria.

This also solves the problem of the user asking for coffee mugs over $500. If there are no matches, you don't give the user 0 items to select from but you give them some of the other items with preference to coffee mugs of any price. Presenting the user with no items to purchase is a lost chance that they might see something they want.

You can implement this in either of the ways you mentioned except you are varying the "order by" clause.

My personal preference is to NOT use stored procedures.

But, if you are working with a large group with experts in database use in the group that can optimize the database usage and keep the stored procedures in top shape, that might be an option.

If its a single person or small team of java developers, don't expect them to be experts in Java and SQL/Database as well. Play to your teams strengths.