# Java backend cunstrutcion for eCommerce filter

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I need some clarifications. Let's say the customer needs an eCommerce Web Page where they can filter "almost" everything that can be filterable.

For example, it should be possible to filter articles (country-related) after brand, brand model, category, collection, stock, price, date uploaded, supplier, etc., etc.
In view of a relational database, that means I need a big query (joining over 15+ Tables every time) that should be very fast and meet the filter criteria.
For the backend, it should be used spring/java.

I did some research and found this [Dynamically applying filter to list of products in ecommerce application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17175443/11945378) (this Q&A is over 8 years old), but I think that there is a better way to solve this than dynamically creating SQL queries.

So to conclude - is there a specific pattern that has to be used or am I missing something?

Please let me know if more information is required in this context.

Comment: For searching and filtering, you can use algolia or Elastic Search search engine . Have a look at them. The database is not good at searching.

Comment: Try with the JPA Criteria API (part 6. in here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries) to dynamically build queries. With modern hardware and well indexed tables it should be very fast. Only if it's not fast enough try other solutions

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi Additional info: I'm currently using the ElasticSearch engine. The search works really good but there is one big drawback -> it takes very long to index all data (over 3 hours) so when an error has to be fixed (like each bug right NOW!!! ;) ) it can't be done due to the long-lasting indexing time.